# With VC 15.4.0, std::function assignment produces C2679 (compiled with 15.3.5)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, stl, functional-programming

The following code compiles just fine with VC 15.3.5:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

class TypeDictionary;
class IStructureField {};

using  FieldFactory = std::function<std::unique_ptr<IStructureField>(TypeDictionary& dict, LPCSTR szName, std::optional<ULONG> ulOffset, std::optional<std::string> strFieldType, std::optional<ULONG> ulFieldSize)>;


int main()
{
FieldFactory ff;

ff = [](TypeDictionary& dict, LPCSTR szName, std::optional<ULONG> ulOffset, std::optional<std::string> szFieldType, std::optional<ULONG> ulFieldSize) -> std::unique_ptr<IStructureField> {
    return  std::unique_ptr<IStructureField>();
};

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following error message with 15.4.0:

```
1>f:\projects\fullpath\fullpath\fullpath.cpp(22): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'main::<lambda_36489dce1cc59e5a8de4329a29806b5a>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\functional(656): note: could be 'std::function<std::unique_ptr<IStructureField,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)> &std::function<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)>::operator =(std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=IStructureField
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\functional(629): note: or       'std::function<std::unique_ptr<IStructureField,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)> &std::function<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)>::operator =(std::function<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)> &&)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=IStructureField
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\functional(612): note: or       'std::function<std::unique_ptr<IStructureField,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)> &std::function<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)>::operator =(const std::function<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> (TypeDictionary &,LPCSTR,std::optional<ULONG>,std::optional<std::string>,std::optional<ULONG>)> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=IStructureField
1>        ]
1>f:\projects\fullpath\fullpath\fullpath.cpp(22): note: while trying to match the argument list '(FieldFactory, main::<lambda_36489dce1cc59e5a8de4329a29806b5a>)'
1>Done building project "FullPath.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

As I saw on cppcon (Stephan's talk), a lot of work has been done on `<functional>`... Could this be related? Any mistake I made?

Workarounds would be fine too.

Edit1: Added the two include files to help understand the issue is not there: Same error...

Edit2: After I repaired my VS installation, the code just compiled. However, the original code did not. I had bumped in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/74313/compiler-error-in-xsmf-control-with-stdoptional-pa.html before and attempted the workaround (which exposed the issue I faced). Without the workaround, the code compiles (but hits the __this issue again...).

Comment: You definitely need to include `<string>` and `<memory>`.

Comment: As I mentioned, this code compiles with just the previous version of MSVC...

Comment: Even if it does one can not rely on some standard library headers being included into some other library headers. Anyway try adding those headers and check whether it fixes the problem.

Comment: You **must** include each header you use things from.  Otherwise you code is undefined.

Comment: Now that is odd.  I just created a WIndows Console application project in VS 17 with an exact copy of your code.  At first I had the old version of the compiler (15.3.xxx) so it built just fine.   But then I upgraded to 15.4, cleaned and built again.  And it built just fine.   Debug and Release, x86 and x64.  

So I'm wondering about project settings now.  Try a clean project and see what happens.

Comment: I have just tried this: create a new project, set language to c++17, disabled precompiled headers. And the error message is still produced... (compiling with command line: cl /std:c++17 TestFunction.cpp)

Comment: Version 19.11.25547

Comment: Just gave it a try on another machine. Code compiled... I will now attempt repair/reinstall and report...

Comment: After I repaired my VS installation, the code just compiled. However, the original code did not. I had bumped in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/74313/compiler-error-in-xsmf-control-with-stdoptional-pa.html before and attempted the workaround (which exposed the issue I faced). Without the workaround, the code compiles (but hits the __this issue again...).